How to delete all json documents in a key with Redis
I have the following structure:
cart:product:apples
cart:product:bananas
cart:product:kiwi

apples, bananas, kiwi are of type JSON and would like to delete them like so.
DEL cart:product:* 

But when running this command it does not work when it's of type JSON, it works if it is a SET for example or if I specify directly which document I want to delete like DEL cart:product:apples
I know it's possible to delete all of them if I iterate trough and than delete, but is there no way to do it with a single command like with the :* ?

Are cart:product:apples, cart:product:bananas, and cart:product:kiwi different keys or are these nested JSON elements?

They are different keys

you can use RedisInsight to delete keys in Bulk.
To do so, open the Bulk Actions in Browser (top right corner), set filter per key type (JSON in this case) and filter the key names by the namespace (cart:product:*).
RedisInsight will delete all the keys per filters set.


I would like to do that with a command but not sure what the command is.

You can use the monitor functionality in Redis Insight to understand how it works.  But there is no single command.
